# dual-booting now have 2 grub-menu's

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb, uefi

I have a Dell Inspirion laptop stock with Windows 8.1, I have added Ubuntu 14.04. Ubuntu install went perfect, rebooted came to the regualar, grub2 menu, (I say regular because it's the same one I've looked at on my old pc for a couple of years) I choose Ubuntu, it loaded a little more, then another screen popped up with the OS choices, although this looks like a Windows based screen, again I choose Ubuntu, and the desktop loaded, and everything ran perfect. Then rebooting into Windows, again I got the old Familiar grub2 menu, and then what looks like a Windows verseion of the OS choice menu, and again Windows loaded and ran perfect.

So there really isn't a problem with having both screens come up, it's just a little annoying to have to make that choice twice. Now I guess I better mention that I installed Ubuntu on a usb hard drive, it did install using the uefi method, as far as I know, because first it works, I seem to remember that it mentioned uefi while installing, although that was a month ago, so I may be remembering wrong. When I boot up I click the F12 button and pull up the boot order menu, and choose the uefi usb device, and Ubuntu loads, or I press F12 and choose hard drive, and Windows loads.

Putting this on usb was actually more of an experiment than anything, just to see if I could make it work. I don't really want to install to my hard drive at this point, even though installing Linux will not void the warranty, if they can say the problem is caused because of the Linux instillation and get out of repairing it, they will. That's what the manufacturer told me, when I called to ask. He was very honest about it, and said that they will get out of fixing it anyway they can, and that's just giving them something to use. I'm using usb 3.0 stuff, so it's just as fast as if it was installed to the hard drive.

So I have two problems, 1. the two OS choice (grub) menu's, and probably nothing I can do about this as long as I'm usb booting 2. having to press F12 every time I restart the machine, even if the usb drive is unhooked and I'm booting into windows, If I don't F12 then choose hard drive, the boot-up just hangs, on a blank screen, it doesn't know where to find the hard drive apparently.

If anyone has any wisdom, or even criticism, I would be glad to hear it, that's the best way to learn.

Thanks for the advice
Robby

Comment: Go into your ubuntu, and run the command 
`sudo grub-install /dev/sda` (or, wherever your grub is installed) and then run : 

 `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

This might help. Comment here if this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably slightly fuzzy on this one as it's been a while, but the boot sequence goes a little like this:
Power on and POST->BIOS Boot Device->MBR on boot device->Boot sector->OS.

So basically, your computer powers on and your BIOS is set to look toward a device for booting (Hard disk, CD-ROM, USB etc.) and it looks for the MBR at the beginning of the disk. The MBR then instructs the computer to look at the location of the disk with further boot information. This is the /boot partition in Linux where GRUB resides. The GRUB config files contain info for where the / mount point is and where the initial files are to start loading the kernel, and it will contain the location of windows installations and how to load them, too. You might want to check the GRUB config files in /boot to see where they point because they may just point to that second loading screen.

Comment: OK, I checked all of the boot files in Ubuntu, and found nothing out of place, but then I got to thinking, it doesn't matter if I'm booting into Linux, or Windows, either way I get two "Choose OS" screens. So it's not a Linux problem, or a Windows problem, it has to be in the bios somewhere, otherwise it would only do it on one OS, not both.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I will go check that right now. But yeah, your right first it sees looks for the device, then looks for booting instructions, then mine is going somewhere else before booting.